# Publish generic (interface based) message and Consume concrete (concrete class) message in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit, message-type

I have this design choice problem and somehow slogging but in vain. It works only in a specific scenario.

I am trying to publish and consume a message in MassTransit. 
Ex: (Publisher - a simple console app)

```
IShape message = GetShape(/**Business Logic will return some concrete object (Circle or square) based on some business inputs**/);  
bus.Publish(message);
```

(Consumers - CircleConsumer and SquareConsumer)

```
 class CircleConsumer : IConsumer<IShape>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IShape> context)
        {
            var circle = context.Message as Circle;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    class SquareConsumer : IConsumer<IShape>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IShape> context)
        {
            var square = context.Message as Square;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

(Consumers configuration in .Net Core Hosted Service Project)

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
                   .AddScoped<SquareConsumer>()
                    .AddScoped<CircleConsumer>()
                    .AddMassTransit(cfg =>
                     {
                         cfg.AddBus(ConfigureBus);
                         cfg.AddConsumer<SquareConsumer>();
                         cfg.AddConsumer<CircleConsumer>();
                     })
                    .AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>())
                    .AddSingleton<IHostedService, TestMTConsumerHostedService>();

                    IBusControl ConfigureBus(IServiceProvider provider)
                    {
                        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                        {
                            var host = cfg.Host(hostContext.Configuration["RabbmitMQ:Server:Host"], hostContext.Configuration["RabbmitMQ:Server:VirtualHost"], h =>
                            {
                                h.Username(hostContext.Configuration["RabbmitMQ:Auth:Username"]);
                                h.Password(hostContext.Configuration["RabbmitMQ:Auth:Password"]);
                            });

                            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("CircleQueue", ep =>
                            {
                                ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                                ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                                ep.Consumer<CircleConsumer>(provider);
                            });

                            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("SquareQueue", ep =>
                            {
                                ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                                ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
                                ep.Consumer<SquareConsumer>(provider);
                            });
                        });
                    }

                });
```

My requirement is to have Publisher publish the message without the knowledge of concrete classes. And the only one of the consumers receive the message based on the message type.

But it looks like both the consumers are receiving the message and also casting doesnt work either. Desired: Suppose, when the publisher send Square object, only Square consumer should receive the call. But, in my case, both SquareConsumer and CircleConsumer receiving the message.

As a workaround, this works:

1. Always publish concrete objects.

   ```
           bus.Publish(new Square());
   ```
2. Declare the consumers with concrete types.

   ```
          class CircleConsumer : IConsumer<Circle>
           {
               public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Circle> context)
               {
                   var circle = context.Message;
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               }
           }

           class SquareConsumer : IConsumer<Square>
           {
               public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Square> context)
               {
                   var square = context.Message;
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               }
           }
   ```

But, it would be great if I could do it generically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your code like this:

```
object message = GetShape(/**Business Logic will return some concrete object (Circle or square) based on some business inputs**/);  
bus.Publish(message);
```

and consumers

```
class CircleConsumer : IConsumer<Circle>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Circle> context)
    {
        // do circle stuff
    }
}

class SquareConsumer : IConsumer<Square>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Square> context)
    {
        // do square stuff
    }
}
```

it will work as expected.

Here I elaborate on the changes:

1. Using `Publish` with an instance of a specific type means using the `Publish<T>(T message)` overload, which uses `T` as the message type. When explicitly setting the message type to `object`, we call the `Publish(object message)` overload. In that case, MassTransit will look up all types that the message implements.
2. You don't need to consume the message of a shared interface type if your aim to consume the concrete type messages. You just need to create consumers for those specific types. As long as you use publish as I described in the previous point, the message will go to both `IShape` and `Circle` exchanges (for example).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have accepted and kind of took a similar approach yesterday. However, I was thinking of not having to change the method signatures of the business related methods and keeping them more cleaner and organized. But hey, we have a working solution already. I have added my approach too as an answer below.

Comment: I definitely know that when you use the code in your question, MT will use the `Publish<T>(T message)` overload, which uses `T` as the message type. The trick here is to use `Publish(object messge`)` , which forces MT to find out the message type. That's why using `object xxx=` instead of var or a concrete type, solves the publishing issue. You might have missed that part, if you only notices changes in consumers.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I went with the approach below finally. However, I wish MassTransit had ability to route messages purely polymorphic in nature. This is just a workaround and not a true solution. Still welcome to new approaches.

Using little help from reflection and kind of friend methods in concrete classes, I arrived at this.

Publisher:

```
            IShape message = GetShape(text);
            var castedMessage = ReflectionHelper.CastToConcreteType(message);
            bus.Publish(castedMessage);

        public static class ReflectionHelper
        {
            public static object CastToConcreteType(object obj)
            {
                MethodInfo castMethod = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());
                return castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
            }
        }
```

Interface and Concrete Classes for message types:

```
    public interface IShape
        {
            public string Color { get;  }
            public string Name { get; }
        }

        public class Circle : IShape, ITypeCastable
    {
            public string Color => "Red";
            public string Name => $"{Color}Circle";
            T ITypeCastable.Cast<T>(object obj) => Cast<T>(obj);
            public static T Cast<T>(object o) => (T)o;
        }
        public class Square : IShape, ITypeCastable
        {
            public string Color => "Green";
            public string Name => $"{Color}Square";
            T ITypeCastable.Cast<T>(object obj) => Cast<T>(obj);
            public static T Cast<T>(object o) => (T)o;
        }

        public interface ITypeCastable
        {
            T Cast<T>(object obj);
        }
```

Consumers: A very minor change by replacing interfaces with concrete class names in generic type supply.

```
    class CircleConsumer : IConsumer<Circle>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Circle> context)
        {
            var circle = context.Message;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    class SquareConsumer : IConsumer<Square>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Square> context)
        {
            var square = context.Message;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```