# MassTransit Sub-Class when published is not consumed

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to create Generic Implementation to publish messages with `MassTransit`.

**BasePublisher**

```
public abstract class BasePublisher
{
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint;

    public BasePublisher(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        this.publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public Task Publish(IntegrationBaseEvent message)
    {
        return publishEndpoint.Publish(message);
    }
}
```

**IntegrationBaseEvent**

```
public class IntegrationBaseEvent
{
    public IntegrationBaseEvent(Guid id, string name, DateTime createdDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        CreationDate = createdDate;
    }

    public IntegrationBaseEvent()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; private set; }
}
```

And I've created events using the abstraction `IntegrationBaseEvent`.

```
public class BusinessCreatedEvent : IntegrationBaseEvent
{
    public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }

    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
}
```

With the interface below, I am trying to publish the message but it not at all consumed

```
public interface IPublisher
{
    Task Publish(IntegrationBaseEvent message);
}
```

It is consumed only when I create a separate publisher for the inherited event `BusinessCreatedEvent` something like below

```
public interface ISubscriptionPublisher
{
    Task Publish(BusinessCreatedEvent message);
}
```

I don't want to create a different publisher and just want to use the abstract publisher like below.

```
public class BusinessCreatedEventHandler 
{
    private readonly IPublisher _publisher;

    public BusinessCreatedEventHandler(IPublisher publisher)
    {
        _publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Task Handle(string id, string name)
    {
        var message = new BusinessCreatedEvent
        {
            BusinessId = id,
            BusinessName = name
        };

        _publisher.Publish(message);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Any ideas to make it generic, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit leverages generics extensively, and limits types to the generic type specified. Since you're specifying the base interface as the generic type in the call to `Publish`, that base interface type is all that is published.

Your question is [similar to the this one, and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60613176/1882) – and the solution is the same. Convert it to `object` and use the `Publish(object message)` overload instead. That way, MassTransit will use the object type (MassTransit will call `message.GetType()` and properly dispatch the message type.

Or, you could make your interface include a generic method as well:

```cs
public interface IPublisher
{
    Task Publish<T>(T message)
        where T : class, IntegrationBaseEvent;
}
```